# I am getting this error Cannot read property 'value' of null in jest testing in react

Tags: reactjs, jestjs

TypeError: Cannot read property 'value' of null

```
   96 |                 <WizardProgressBar steps={wizardSteps} />
   97 |             </div>
>  98 |             <ErrorMessage show={userError.value.toUpperCase() == "SHOW"}>
      |                                           ^
   99 |                 The username you entered is already in use.  Please enter a new username.
  100 |             </ErrorMessage>
  101 |             <ErrorMessage show={passError.value.toUpperCase() == "SHOW"}>
```

Comment: userError is null. You must check it before use userError.value

Comment: Thanks for suggestion..I have check but issue not solve!

Comment: Show please your check in your question

Answer (score 0):

In the place where the error is pointing, you should check if `useError` exists:

```
<ErrorMessage show={useError && userError.value.toUpperCase() == "SHOW"}>
```